# Python selenium script to continue running if element is not found

Tags: python, selenium

I am dealing with a pop up issue that seems to be random before I click on a button. I want to know if there is any way I can check if the element is displayed and click it, if it is not displayed, i want it to continue running the script. my current script keeps getting an error. when the pop up is displayed, my script runs PERFECT. my error takes place on my script at the

```
onetouch = self.driver.find_element _by_xpath("").
```

Here is a picture of my error:

[image]

```
        self.driver.get(redirecturl)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(180)
        login_frame = self.driver.find_element_by_name('injectedUl')
        # switch to frame to access inputs
        self.driver.switch_to.frame(login_frame)
        # we now have access to the inputs
        email = self.driver.find_element_by_id('email')
        password = self.driver.find_element_by_id('password')
        button = self.driver.find_element_by_id('btnLogin')



        # input your email and password below
        email.send_keys('')
        password.send_keys('')
        button.click()
        #############

        onetouch = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='memberReview']/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a")
        if onetouch.is_displayed():
            time.sleep(2)
            onetouch.click()
        else:
            print "onetouch not present....continuing script"
        button2 = self.driver.find_element_by_id('confirmButtonTop')
        button2.click()
        button3 = self.driver.find_element_by_name('dwfrm_payment_paypal')
        # if you want to test the program without placing an order, delete the button3.click() below this.........
        button3.click
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually `find_element_by_xpath` always returns either element or throws exception, So if there is no element by provided locator you can't execute `is_displayed()`. You should try using `find_elements_by_xpath` instead and check the length as below :-

```
onetouch = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='memberReview']/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a")

    if len(onetouch) > 0:
        time.sleep(2)
        onetouch[0].click()
    else:
        print "onetouch not present....continuing script"
        -------
```

Comment: @Tonysanchez, yes you should edit your script with this change ...:)

Comment: @Tonysanchez yeah sure let me know if any problem...:)

Comment: okay, so im getting the same error because it couldnt find      "self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='memberReview']/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a")"   because the pop up didnt show up

Comment: Once omit the `.` from xpath and try as: `self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='memberReview']/div[2]/div/div/div‌​[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a")` and let me know..

Comment: No, because if element not found with the ID it will throw `nosuchelementexception`, you can use `find.elements_by_id` instead and check length...

Comment: the problem is,  "self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='memberReview']/div[2]/div/div/div‌​[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a")" is only present when the pop up shows up, when it doesnt pop up, this element is no where on the page

Comment: Ate you sure `find_elements_by_xpath` throwing exception?? Because it's always returns empty list if there is no element by provided locator... Strange why are you getting exception...

Comment: sorry for the late reply. im testing this agian to make sure i did it all right.

Comment: i added a picture to your first comment showing my error.

Comment: Man please check your code, this line executed successfully problem may be other line of code, please debug it carefully, it may be in else part when you are going to find element by I'd. Check it... Exception is clearly giving line number of code..check this line of code is it this code or something other..

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
    time.sleep(2)
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='memberReview']/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a").click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    print "onetouch not present....continuing script"
```

Comment: Can you share `HTML` for target page? Obviously, problem not in element with provided `XPath`

Comment: im using this on an auto checkout after logging into my paypal, a pop up occationally come out.

Comment: Sorry, but not enough information provided. I need more details to be able to help you

Comment: It worked! Problem was that I was still in frame! I had to return the driver to default before using your solution. Thank you!